# convert mime mails from the input stream to readable text

Tags: php, mime

Can I get any help for php mime email parser/decoder like https://code.google.com/p/php-mime-mail-parser/ which does not involve any installations. I even tried Zend and decoder from phpclasses.org, but it did not help. I am unable to find how to give the input to program and take the output from as there is no tutorial for this

My aim: I need to convert mime mails from the input stream to readable text

Please help

Comment: Can you provide an example in your question? One or more example input and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this library, I have used in many application but make sure that you should have mail parser extension installed in your server.

http://codepad.org/zgUEf8lY